# iusse with scrollable layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I don't know why but my layout is not scrollable. I want it to scroll.

Here's my configuration...............................................................................................

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/signor_pomidor"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_logut_bg"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

SCREENSHOT:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An1rJ.png)

Comment: Your layout will scroll if the content of your layout exceeds the screen height. That's so basic so please make sure your layout's content exceeds the screen height.

Comment: Please also change height and with to match_parent since fill_parent is deprecated

Comment: I tried your code and it worked perfectly. Also, based on the given photo I guess that you want the view to scroll when the keyboard appears, right? As a note, I tried it on an emulator with API 22. Can you tell us on what version did you test it?

Comment: You are using deprecated constants, FILL_PARENT, you should change it to MATCH_PARENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because the content of the layout isn't higher than the screen. The point of a ScrollView is allowing more content to be on the same screen by adding scrolling. This of course doesn't work if there is nothing to scroll.

If you want to scroll either way, you have three options:

1. Set the height of the ScrollView itself to be smaller than the content

   - Set the height of the ScrollView to for an instance 200dp
2. Add more content

   - This doesn't need a description; it's all in the title
3. Add more margins

   - For an instance, add `fill_parent` to the last button.

Though you're better off just not using a ScrollView if the combined height of the content fits within the screen. There's no need to scroll if everything fits inside the screen, especially since the entire layout is dedicated to a single purpose (a layout where the login is a small part and (by design) should take up less space, ScrollViews would be necessary. Obviously, if the content was different and took up more space you may need a ScrollView as well).

In addition, `match_parent` is deprecated. Use `android:marginTop="400dp"` instead.

**TL;DR:** You can't scroll a ScrollView if the height (with vertical ScrollViews, width with horizontal ones) of the content doesn't take up more space than the screen

Comment: Is there actually a need to scroll? Are you sure that the content _actually goes outside the screen_?

Comment: Is the content actually outside the screen?

Comment: in what sense is outside of the screen?

Comment: If there is content outside the visible part of the screen it will scroll. I improved the question. I added marginTop to 400dp on a button. Try that and see what happens

Comment: I also explained why what happens happen